# A complex count rows with SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to combine COUNTs from an Access database file using an SQL Query and I need your help.

Here's my database columns

```
[Name] [Project Type] [Project Phase]
```

In each row, I have the name of an employee and the type of project he (or she) is working on (type 1 or type 2) and the project phase ( complete / incomplete / in progress ).

The result from the Query I'm trying to build should look like this.

```
[Name] [Type1 Complete][Type1 Incomplete][Type1 InProgress] (...)
Jack          0                2                  3         (...)
John          3                0                  0         (...)
```

Is there a way to combine different  SQL COUNT within the same query and group them by the name of the employee ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why `sql-server` and `mysql` tags if you're using MS Access???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  You'll need to use a case statement to derive your type1... columns.  Something like

```
select [Name],
count (case when [Project Type] = 1 then <whatever you're counting> else null end) as [Type1 Complete]` 
from <your table> 
group by [NAME]
```

EDIT:  Didn't catch the Access tag. If this really is Access, you can't use CASE.  You'll need to use IIF. So you would end up with something like

```
count (iif([Project Type]=1,<whatever you're counting>,null) as [Type1 Complete]
```

Comment: In MS Access, you can also use the `switch` statement instead of `iif`, a la `case`.